# Best practice: prepopulate SlugField in Django (without Admin module)

Tags: python, django, slug

In the early days of Django it was possible to prepopulate a SlugField within the Model.

In the Admin module i would use

```
prepopulated_fields = {'slug':('title',),}
```

I found a snippet that handles it [Unique Slugify](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/690/) but I doubt that it is the best way.

So what would be the best practise to autogenerate a SlugField without using the Admin module?

Id like to use a ModelForm to integrade the form in the frontpage, which should autogenerate a unique slug for the URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just cut and paste from one of my older (as in less well coded) models. It should show you an idea, with just a little polish, should work.

```
from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify
def get_nickname(self):
    nick = self.name
    vowels = ('a','e','i','o','u')
    first_letter = nick[:1]
    nick = nick[1:]

    for vowel in vowels: nick = nick.replace(vowel,'')
    nick = first_letter + nick
    if len(nick) > 8:
        nick = nick[:7]
    return nick

def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, using=None):
    if not self.nickname:
        self.nickname = self.get_nickname() if len(self.name)>8 else self.name
    self.slug = slugify(self.nickname)
    slug_test = SomeModel.objects.filter(slug=self.slug, id=self.id) # corrected to use a generic model name
    if slug_test:
        count = slug_test.count
        self.slug = "{}{}".format(self.slug[:len(self.slug)-1], count)

    super(SomeModel, self).save()
```

UPDATE: tighter code for the get_nick method ...

```
>>> name = 'alabama'
>>> vowels = {'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'}
>>> nick = name[0] + ''.join(l for l in name[1:] if l not in vowels)
>>> nick
'albm'
```

FWIW: I just updated my model, eliminating the `get_nickname` method, and adding a simple `lambda` to the top of the `save` method:

```
vowels = {'a','e','i','o','u'}
create_nick = lambda name: name[0] + ''.join(l for l in name[1:] if l not in vowels)[:7]
if not self.nickname:
    self.nickname = create_nick(self.name) if len(self.name)>8 else self.name
...
```

Comment: thank you! i also found another feature-rich app for unique slugs [django-autoslug](https://bitbucket.org/neithere/django-autoslug)

Comment: No doubt there is some serious third-party apps out there! I went light-weight, importing `slugify` and adding the `if slug_test` to insure uniqueness. All my verbage is a little silly, so thanks for the indulgence

Comment: Your answer is definitely the light-weight and in most cases the better solution - Thanks for the great update. But why do you check for vowels and the length? Do you try to keep the URL as short as possible?

Comment: Someone's url 3 or 4 slug fields and a numerical identify at the end of the url. I wanted to make it scannable without too much length. There are only so many letters the iPhone can show in a url, for example.